# What is the appropriate (postpositive) adjective for this?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Many believed that John the Baptist was Elijah **incarnate.**

Where **incarnate** means

*invested with bodily and especially human nature and form*

But suppose I want to liken someone to some fictional character who exists but in the imagination, what adjective used postpositively would apply in that case?

This, for example:

> His friends think that he is Bilbo Baggins....

Comment: 'Many believed .... Here _reincarnate_ means

personified or typified, as a quality or idea.' That's not what the article you link to says. It spells out 'The religious concept of reincarnation is the belief that when a human body dies, the spirit that inhabited it is reborn into another body.' So 'Many believed that John the Baptist was Elijah reincarnate' means 'Many believed that John the Baptist was Elijah, returned, with a new body, and for some reason with a new name'.

Comment: Thank you, @Edwin Ashworth. I have edited the question.

Comment: No. 'Incarnate' means

'invested with bodily and especially human nature and form'.

Comment: As adjectives they're synonymous, right? @Edwin Ashworth.

Comment: No. You can use say either 'remounted his horse' or 'mounted his horse' when it's the third time that day, but not if it's his first time in the saddle. And 'reincarnate' must carry the sense of 'not for the first time'. Of course it gets tricky with metaphorical usages; one can certainly say 'Jack is Bilbo Baggins come back to life!' [the allusion is that Bilbo 'died' when one suspended pathetic fallacy, ie started concentrating on real life ... then saw/thought of a real person one thought very like Tolkien's character].

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't care for a postpositive participial phrase instead, like *made flesh* or *come again* or *brought to life*?

Comment: @tchrist: No special reason. Just a magpie instinct to amass innumerable words.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the word '**incarnate**', as it literally means '*in the flesh*' - as Bilbo Baggins has never really been in the flesh, the 're' in 'reincarnate' doesn't make sense.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/incarnate)'s definition:

> (especially of a deity or spirit) embodied in human form.

E.g. *His friends think he is Bilbo Baggins incarnate*.

Comment: Thank you. I think this works. Still let's wait and see if someone has to offer something more precise.